# Order post by date

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I've created a list of post and now I want order this list by date of publishing. If I use *order_by(-post_publishing_date)* in the view the shell show me this error:

> NameError: name 'post_publishing_date' is not defined

models.py

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    post_short_description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    post_contents = models.TextField()
    post_publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(AuthorModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="connected_author")
    post_keyconcept = models.ManyToManyField(KeyConceptModel, related_name="connected_keyconcept")
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Slug", unique="True")
    post_highlighted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("singlepostManuscriptusView", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Articolo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Articoli"
```

views.py

```
class SinglePostGDV(DetailView):
    model = PostModel
    template_name = "manuscriptus_post_detail.html"


class ListPostGDV(ListView):
    model = PostModel
    template_name = "manuscriptus_home.html"
    queryset = PostModel.objects.filter().order_by(-post_publishing_date)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("it/blog/", ListPostGDV.as_view(), name="homeManuscriptusView"),
    path("it/blog/<slug:slug>/", SinglePostGDV.as_view(), name="singlepostManuscriptusView"), 
]
```

**What I did wrong?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## *Ad hoc* ordering

Well Python is correct. There is no *identifier* `post_publishing_date`, you pass the name of the column *through a string*, so:

```
class ListPostGDV(ListView):
    model = PostModel
    template_name = "manuscriptus_home.html"
    queryset = PostModel.objects.filter().order_by('-post_publishing_date')
```

## Define an *inherent* ordering on the model

Note that you can also give a model an "inherent" ordering in the `Meta` class:

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    post_short_description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    post_contents = models.TextField()
    post_publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(AuthorModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="connected_author")
    post_keyconcept = models.ManyToManyField(KeyConceptModel, related_name="connected_keyconcept")
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name="Slug", unique="True")
    post_highlighted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_title

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse("singlepostManuscriptusView", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-post_publishing_date']
        verbose_name = "Articolo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Articoli"
```

If you do this, all queries to this model will *implicitly* be ordered by `-post_publishing_date`. So this means that you can not "forget" to order the objects properly.

So then you do not have to order it *in the views*. You can of course only define one such "inherent" ordering, and it is not clear if you want to use one here.

Answer (score 1):

order_by argument should be string:

```
queryset = PostModel.objects.filter().order_by('-post_publishing_date')
```